# Python http.server with inifinite loop in background

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I have a very basic python `http.server`. It gets requests on `127.0.0.1:8081` and returns `Hello World` - everything is fine)

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class Server(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):

        message = 'Hello world!'

        # ... http stuff: headers, status

        self.wfile.write(bytes(message, 'utf8'))

        return

print('Starting server...')

server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 8081)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, Server)

print('Running server...')

httpd.serve_forever()
```

But I want to make an infinite `while True` loop in bacground, to make some magic each minute, regardless of requests.

And if I add somewhere before `httpd.serve_forever()` something like:

```
import time
while True:
    print('Some magic')
    time.sleep(60)
```

Http server will not serve requests due to beeing busy by printting `Some magic`

I cant figure out, what should i use? Asincio? Multithreading? May be Celery? Or is there a way to temporary stop this loop in `Server.do_GET`, then run it again after request proceed?

Big thx for you answers!

**EDIT**

I just found this solution instead of `while True` loop:

```
import threading

def infinite_loop():
    print('Some magic')
    threading.Timer(60, infinite_loop).start()

infinite_loop()
```

Is it a normal plan for python 3.5 ? Or there are better ways?

Comment: You already gave a reasonable answer to yourself - fire off a thread.  Of course, there's more than likely more complexity that you hint about, probably involving synchronizing access to a resource, for instance, a cache.

Comment: There are some non blocking (asynchronous) web server available for Python. like twisted or tornadoweb
Take a look at http://nichol.as/asynchronous-servers-in-python